# Linking against static Lua libraries on macOS

Tags: macos, cmake, lua

I'm trying to compile and link a program (using CMake) that uses Lua 5.3's C interface on `Mac OS X 10.15.7`. However I have these problems:

- `brew install lua@5.3` only installs dynamic libraries
- I cannot copy static libraries built from source to `/usr/local` due to System Integrity Protection (?)
- I don't know how to make CMake find the libraries if I put them anywhere else (using `find_package(Lua 5.3 REQUIRED)`

What's the easiest way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you are trying to use Lua's C API, which means that you need access to the principal header files `lua.h`, `lualib.h`, and `lauxlib.h`, as well the static library `liblua.a` that is created when the interpreter is built.

I would recommend downloading `lua-5.3.5.tar.gz` from [lua.org](http://www.lua.org) and then building from source.

This can be done easily from the Terminal:

```
$ wget http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
$ cd lua-5.3.5
$ make macosx
```

After that you should be able to do `make install` as well, which copies the Lua interpreter to `/usr/local/bin`, I believe.

If you do not want the key Lua header files put into your include path, build your program with `-I` and `-L` flags. Also, don't forget the `-llua -ldl -lm` flags when linking your program.